# Solving a logic puzzle (Kuromasu, Where is black cells) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, puzzle, clpfd

I have some problems with solving puzzle. I haven't found solution for this puzzle anywhere, but I tried to write it in Prolog, but I think my solution won't be fast (I generate every solution and delete them if they aren't possible or correct).
This is my problem:
(I found a name of that puzzle, here is the link with all rules of that puzzle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuromasu).
Now I have a different question, which method would be the quite easy to write and quite fast to solve it in Prolog. I thought about transforming my list of fields into a undirected graph, or maybe there is another method to search my list vertically (head after head)?

In:

```
0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0
0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2
0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
8, 0, 13,0, 0, 0, 0
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0
0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0
```

Result:

```
0, #, 0, 5, 0, 0, #
0, 5, 0, 0, 0, #, 2
0, #, 0, #, 7, 0, 4
#, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, #
8, 0, 13,0, 0, 0, 0
5, 0, 0, 0, #, 6, 0
#, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, #
```

Comment: Do you have a name or link for the puzzle? The title is not very good..

Comment: I tried to find a name of this puzzle, but I don't know.
How can I change the title to make it more clear?

Comment: The name of the puzzle would be a start :-) "Solving XYZ in Prolog?" where XYZ is the puzzle name or puzzle archetype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of puzzles is called Kuromasu. Here is a page that solves it with SWI-Prolog and finite domain constraints: http://jfoutelet.developpez.com/articles/kuromasu/

Comment: Thank You very much, that information is very useful.
But there is another problem, I don't understand French and I think, I can't use #_ like predicates.